# Can't retrieve custom option from order items

Tags: magento2, product, cart

I am writing an extension where I need to place an order with the items already in the user's cart (added programmatically). I have been successful with this, however my orders lose custom options added via `$_product->addCustomOption()`.

```
$addOptns['my_custom_option'] = 3;
foreach ($addOptns as $key => $value) {
    $_product->addCustomOption( $key, $value);
}
$params = array(
    'product' => 123, //product Id
    'qty'   => 100    //quantity of product
);
$this->_cart->addProduct(
    $_product,
    $params
);
$this->_cart->save();
$quote = $this->_cart->getQuote();

...[shipping and payment config]...

$order_id = $this->cartManagementInterface->placeOrder($quote->getId());
```

When I try to receive `my_custom_option` from the order that is placed, I get null.

```
var_dump($item->getCustomOptions()); // NULL
```

Any guess what is wrong with my approach?

Note: This is not a 'custom option' like those created in the admin UI nor do I expect it to be, I use these custom options for other customized processes and they are not directly user selectable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order object does not take custom options from quote but you can force it with event

```
sales_model_service_quote_submit_before
```

check this tutorial: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-additional-options-in-magento-2/. it covers your case completely

Comment: Thanks for this, it took some significant changes to work for my specific case but seems to work. I'm still surprised there isn't something more direct.

Comment: Yes the sales_model_service_quote_submit_before is not working, is there have any other event for accomplish the task

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve by a plugin in Magento 2.2.*

First of all, we need to create an observer file and one Magento event file to implement this functionality.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_load_after">
        <observer name="set_additional_options" instance="CompanyName\ModuleName\Model\SetAdditionalOptions" />
    </event>    
</config>
```

Once you have created this file, now you need to Create another file and named as: CompanyName\ModuleName/Model/SetAdditionalOptions.php

```
<?php
namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;

class SetAdditionalOptions implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_request;    
    public function __construct(RequestInterface $request, Json $serializer = null) 
    {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->serializer = $serializer ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json::class);
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        // Check and set information according to your need
        $product = $observer->getProduct();                    
        if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_cart_add') { //checking when product is adding to cart
            $product = $observer->getProduct();
            $additionalOptions = [];
            $additionalOptions[] = array(
                'label' => "Release Date", //Custom option label
                'value' => $product->getReleaseDate(), //Custom option value
            );                        
            $product->addCustomOption('additional_options', $this->serializer->serialize($additionalOptions));
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Now, We need to create a plugin for the retrieve custom option from cart to order.

First We need to create di.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem">
        <plugin name="unique_name" type="CompanyName\ModuleName\Model\Plugin\Quote\ToOrderItem" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Once you have created this file, now you need to Create another file and named as: CompanyName\ModuleName\Model\Plugin\Quote\ToOrderItem.php

```
<?php
namespace ZCompanyName\ModuleName\Model\Plugin\Quote;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem as QuoteToOrderItem;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;
class ToOrderItem
{    
    public function __construct(Json $serializer = null) 
    {        
        $this->serializer = $serializer ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json::class);
    }

    public function aroundConvert(QuoteToOrderItem $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $item,
        $data = []
    ) {
        // Get Order Item
        $orderItem = $proceed($item, $data);               

        $additionalOptions = $item->getOptionByCode('additional_options');        
        // Check if there is any additional options in Quote Item                    
        if (count($additionalOptions) > 0) {
            // Get Order Item's other options
            $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
            // Set additional options to Order Item
            $options['additional_options'] = $this->serializer->unserialize($additionalOptions->getValue());
            $orderItem->setProductOptions($options);
        }

        return $orderItem;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @dhairya Its working for me above version 2.2.*, you save my day bro!

Comment: I have follow this step but i am not getting any result

Comment: Custom option is showing on cart and checkout page but I am not able to place order after using plugin. Getting error: {"message":"A server error stopped your order from being placed. Please try to place your order again."}

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

**Retrieve custom options of products present any order**

```
$orderObject = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order'); 

// load by order id
$orderId = 1; // YOUR ORDER ID
$order = $orderObject->load($orderId);

// load by order increment id
// $incrementId = '000000001'; // YOUR ORDER INCREMENT ID
// $order = $orderObject->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);

$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems(); // get all items aren't marked as deleted and that do not have parent item; for e.g. here associated simple products of a configurable products are not fetched

// Order items can also be fetched with the following functions
// $items = $order->getAllItems(); // get all items that are not marked as deleted
// $items = $order->getItems(); // get all items

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $options = $item->getProductOptions();        
    if (isset($options['options']) && !empty($options['options'])) {        
        foreach ($options['options'] as $option) {
            echo 'Title: ' . $option['label'] . '<br />';
            echo 'ID: ' . $option['option_id'] . '<br />';
            echo 'Type: ' . $option['option_type'] . '<br />';
            echo 'Value: ' . $option['option_value'] . '<br />' . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

However, using ObjectManager directly for that is not a great solution. You can still use the code with dependency injection as the below:

- Open the block class **Yourcompany_HelloWorld**, then inject the object of \Magento\Sales\Model\Order in the constructor of my module’s block class.

> app/code/Yourcompany/HelloWorld/Block/HelloWorld.php

```
<?php
namespace Yourcompany\HelloWorld\Block;
class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_orderModel;    

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $orderModel,
        array $data = []
        )
        {        
            $this->_orderModel = $orderModel;
            parent::__construct($context, $data);
        }

        public function getOrderItems($orderId) 
        {
            $order = $this->_orderModel->load($orderId);
            return $order->getAllVisibleItems();        
        }
}
?>
```

> Like that, you can use the function in the .phtml file.

```
$orderId = 1; // YOUR ORDER ID
$items = $block->getOrderItems($orderId);

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $options = $item->getProductOptions();        
    if (isset($options['options']) && !empty($options['options'])) {        
        foreach ($options['options'] as $option) {
            echo 'Title: ' . $option['label'] . '<br />';
            echo 'ID: ' . $option['option_id'] . '<br />';
            echo 'Type: ' . $option['option_type'] . '<br />';
            echo 'Value: ' . $option['option_value'] . '<br />' . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

That is all things you will use to retrieve value product custom option cart order in Magento 2.